# Cleanup script with exclusions

Tags: autohotkey

```
Glob(list, A_AppData "Local\Company\Program 1\Program 1\*.*")
Glob(list, A_AppData "Local\Company\Program 2\Program 2\*.*")

Loop, Parse, list, `n 
{
FileGetAttrib, FolderOrFile, %A_LoopField%
IfInString, FolderOrFile, D
    FileRemoveDir, %A_LoopField%, 1
else
    FileDelete, %A_LoopField%
}

MsgBox, Clean-up complete.

;Uncomment (Remove the semi-colon) this next line if you want to see what couldn't be deleted.
;MsgBox %list%

Glob(ByRef list, Pattern, IncludeDirs=1)
{
    if (i:=RegExMatch(Pattern,"[*?]")) && (i:=InStr(Pattern,"\",1,i+1))
        Loop, % SubStr(Pattern, 1, i-1), 2
            Glob(list, A_LoopFileLongPath . SubStr(Pattern,i), IncludeDirs)
    else
        Loop, %Pattern%, %IncludeDirs%
            list .= (list="" ? "" : "`n") . A_LoopFileLongPath
}
```

1. What does `Glob` do exactly?
2. What is the difference between `*` and `*.*` in the [original script](https://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/1187-quick-cleanup-script-all-user-profiles)? I only want to delete the contents of the specified directories.
3. How can I exclude files with certain extensions from being deleted?

Comment: Glob is going through all the directories and sub directories, adding all files that match the pattern into `list`. Then there is a loop that goes through `list` and deletes every file.

Comment: I think `*` is matching directories, and `*.*` is matching files. So they include both if they intend to clear the contents of the folder completely.

Comment: `list .= (list="" ? "" : "\`n") . A_LoopFileLongPath` is the line that is adding files into the `list` to be deleted. If you want to exclude a type of file, add an if statement there. Check [A_LoopFileExt](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/LoopFile.htm#LoopFileExt)

Comment: I'm still learning AutoHotKey, so I can't explain the code with any more than a few educated guesses. I hope you can figure it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
EnvGet, A_LocalAppData, LocalAppData
Glob(list, A_LocalAppData "\Company\Program 1\Program 1\*.*")
Glob(list, A_LocalAppData "\Company\Program 2\Program 2\*.*")
...    
        Loop, %Pattern%, %IncludeDirs%
            if !InStr(A_LoopFileExt, "ext")
                list .= (list="" ? "" : "`n") . A_LoopFileLongPath
}
```